# Angular - Hide Ionic Tab Bar component when clicked on different route (Product Details Page)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, angular-structural-directive

I am attempting to hide an ionic tab bar when I click on an product item thats redirected to the product details page. I've attempted to use other lifecycle methods such as `ngAfterViewInit(), ngAfterViewChecked()`, even tried to `setTimeOut()`. Currently using a structural directive `ngIf(),` to hide the component, but it hides for all routes, not the one specified. I've tried to render it conditionally as well, but breaks the code completely.

app.componet.ts:

```
 @Component({
  template: `
    <app-tabbar> *ngIf="showComponent"></app-tabbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  showComponent: boolean = false;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.forEach((event) => {
      if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
        this.showComponent = true;
        console.log('URL', event.url);
        if (event.url.startsWith('/product/')) {
          console.log(' tabbar does show');
          this.showComponent = false;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

app.component.html:

```
  <div *ngIf="showComponent" class="showComponent">
    <app-tabbar></app-tabbar>
  </div>
```

Might also be worth mentioning that when the page breaks I get an error, that I've never seen before. It seems as thought I'm trying to hide the Tab Bar before the DOM even has access to it.

Error:

```
product.resolver.ts:27 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')
```

I'm wondering if it has to do with the navigation as a whole.

My thought is that instead of just having all the screens listed as children under the `TabnavPage`, we could put a path to the PDP outside, nestled between the `path: 'tab-nav'` and `path: ''` objects.

I've also saw a website that suggested creating a promise, resolving it immediately, and adding a handler with `then()` which would run on the next tick.  but that's probably functionally equivalent to `setTimeout(0)` so maybe won't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same need in my app. I use css property display and Ionic life cycle ionViewWillEnter / ionViewWillLeave.

**TS FILE of the page where you need to hide**

```
ionViewWillEnter() {

const tabBar = document.getElementById('app-tab-bar');
if (tabBar !== null) {
  tabBar.style.display = 'none';
}

}

 ionViewWillLeave() {

const tabBar = document.getElementById('app-tab-bar');
if (tabBar !== null) {
  tabBar.style.display = 'flex';
}
}
```

**HTML File of the tab bar**

```
<ion-tabs >
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" color="primary" id="app-tab-bar">
    // content of your tab bar
  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach would be to use the Router to check for the exact route that the user is navigating to, instead of just checking the URL. You can use the Router.url property for this:

```
@Component({
      template: `
        <app-tabbar *ngIf="showComponent"></app-tabbar>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      `,
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      showComponent: boolean = true;
    
      constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
          if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this.showComponent = !this.router.url.startsWith('/product/');
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Now, the boolean is set to true by default, and will be set to false when the user navigates to a route starting with `"/product/".`

This approach will ensure that the tab bar is hidden only on the exact route you specify.